# Thumbnails sheet or indexprint generator

Tags: thumbnail

I need a software (freeware or open source) for creating thumbnail sheets - indexprints. The idea is that I have a folder with photos (usually 4-5 photos) and I drag them into software window. It must be possible to insert text into the header and footer created index print.

I want to export the result as an image or PDF file.I know that XnView can do indexprint, but there is not drag & drop, which is a very important function.

It can be browser application, but must run without server.

Thanks.

Comment: on which operating system(s) it has to run?

Comment: It has to run on Windows.